# Objective-C dynamic_cast?

Tags: objective-c

Is there an Objective-C equivalent of C++'s dynamic_cast?

It can be faked using this:

```
MyClass *safeObject = [object isKindOfClass: [MyClass class]]
                      ? (MyClass *)originalObject : nil;
```

But this is a lot of code to type, even if I don't need to type it often.

I am a bit rusty so this might not be quite right, but I believe the equivalent in C++ would be:

```
MyClass safeObject = dynamic_cast<MyClass>(orginalObject);
```

The context here is a block where the parameter is defined as a type of a more generic class, but in this block I "know" it's a specific subclass. Nevertheless, I don't want to just cast it blindly with `(MyClass *)originalObject` and ignore a theoretically possible error.

To be clear, while I'd love a `dynamic_cast`, I'd be happy with an alternate approach to safely handle this case as well.

Comment: In the worst case, you could write a macro for this.

Comment: Objective-C is duck-typed. Quite honestly, "complicated" casts are kinda rowing against the language.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking I probably asked the wrong question here. Whatever question I *should have* asked had an answer of "just use `NSAssert([object isKindOfClass: [MyClass class]], @"blahblah")` because you're not expecting it anyway." :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're willing to use Objective-C++, you can write this pretty easily:

```
template<typename T> inline T* objc_cast(id from) {
    if ([from isKindOfClass:[T class]]) {
        return static_cast<T*>(from);
    }
    return nil;
}
```

This should behave exactly as `dynamic_cast<>` except for obj-c objects.

---

If you want to stick with vanilla Obj-C you can get similar behavior with a class method on `NSObject`:

```
@interface NSObject (Cast)
+ (instancetype)cast:(id)from;
@end

@implementation NSObject (Cast)
+ (instancetype)cast:(id)from {
    if ([from isKindOfClass:self]) {
        return from;
    }
    return nil;
}
@end
```

This version just isn't as nice to use since you have to say something like

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton cast:someView];
```

In both versions the resulting value is `nil` if the cast fails.

Comment: This second example is *exactly* what I was looking for. And kind of brilliantly simple. Thank you.

Comment: that is a lovely use of the instancetype operator, so the compiler and the Xcode autocomplete can immediately start using the converted type

Comment: I'm a conditional operator partisan, which also makes this a one-liner:  

    `+(instancetype)cast:(id)from {return [from isKindOfClass:self] ? from : nil; }`

Answer (score 9):

Try this macro:

```
#define objc_dynamic_cast(obj, cls) \
    ([obj isKindOfClass:(Class)objc_getClass(#cls)] ? (cls *)obj : NULL)
```

And also don't forget to

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>
```

Use it like:

```
MyClass *safeObject = objc_dynamic_cast(originalObject, MyClass);
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I wrapped your macro and added the (cls *) to satisfy a compiler warning. Great job! I hesitated to use a macro here because of Xcode's edit in scope, but it seems to work wonderfully.

Comment: Would you mind adding a line showing how to use this macro (for greener outsiders). Thanks.

Comment: I added one. (H2CO3: If you feel I'm messing up your answer, feel free to revert. Just trying to help future readers!)

Comment: Given the nature of the problem, wouldn't it be better for the code to blow up when the object can't be safely cast?

Comment: Yes, I think that's a better answer to the problem. At this point, though, I'm trying to play fair with the question I actually asked. :)

Comment: @StevenFisher no problem, I appreciate it. I don't mind people editin my answers as long as it's not offensive :)

Comment: instead of `(Class)objc_getClass(#cls)` why not just `[cls class]`?

Comment: Because `cls` may not be available at compile-time, in that case OP would get linker errors (yep, these are those nice things called "reflection" and "dynamism" in Obj-C...)

Comment: Nothing's wrong with it. It's still up-voted. But Kevin nailed the desired effect with something simpler.

Answer (score 3):

1. I don't think there is.
2. I think the space for a bug is quite small here.
3. But if you insist, a macro will do fine?