# C# "as" keyword in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, oop, casting

Is there a cast keyword in Objective-C like C# (`as`):

```
Foo bar = new Foo();
Foo tmp = bar as Foo;
```

Is this possible in Objective-C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent of `as` in Objective-C. There is regular type casting (C-style).

If you want to check the type of the object, be sure to call `isKindOfClass:`.

To write the equivalent of:

```
Foo bar = new Foo();
Foo tmp = bar as Foo;
```

You'd write:

```
Foo *bar = [Foo new];
Foo *tmp = ([bar isKindOfClass:[Foo class]]) ? (Foo *)bar : nil;
```

You could always write this up as a category like:

```
@implementation NSObject (TypeSafeCasting)

- (id) asClass:(Class)aClass{
   return ([self isKindOfClass:aClass]) ? self : nil;
}

@end
```

Then you could write it like:

```
Foo *bar = [Foo new];
Foo *tmp = [bar asClass:[Foo class]];
```

Comment: Note that this type of meta-programming in Objective-C is generally a "code smell" indicating that your architecture is far afield of the norms of the language and frameworks.

Comment: @bbum, just to clarify, you are not arguing against the use of categories, but rather the need for the `as` feature from C#?

Comment: Categories generally suck, too.  They are often a crutch that enables poor design.

Answer (score 1):

No, no such keyword exists but you could emulate such behavior with a macro.

```
#define AS(x,y) ([(x) isKindOfClass:[y class]] ? (y*)(x) : nil)

@interface Foo : NSObject
@end
@implementation Foo
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        Foo *bar = [[Foo alloc] init];
        Foo *tmp = AS(bar, Foo);

        NSLog(@"bar as Foo: %@", tmp);

        bar = [NSArray array];
        tmp = AS(bar, Foo);
        NSLog(@"bar as Foo: %@", tmp);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> bar as Foo: `<Foo: 0x682f2d0>`
>   bar as Foo: (null)

I would suggest just checking `isKindOfClass:` directly rather than using a poorly named macro like `AS`. Also if the first paramater of the macro is an expression e.g (`[foo anotherFoo]`) it will be evaluated twice. That could lead to performance issues or other issues if `anotherFoo` has side effects.

Comment: What should I move the advice not to use it to the top :)

Answer (score -1):

Typecasting (it's just C):

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
Bar *bar = (Bar *)foo;
```

NB: you can shoot yourself in the foot with this, be careful.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but this isn't the same thing.  `as` checks RTTI to verify type compatibility.  c# also has c-style casting, so this isn't really what was being asked.

Comment: @Donnie [I know that as well.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557756/objective-c-dynamic-cast/10557838#10557838)

Comment: I am really confused as to why this is getting up-votes, this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @H2CO3, I don't think you understand the `as` keyword. The `as` keyword will return `nil` if the object being casted is not of the appropriate class. Using your example I can cast an `NSNumber` to an `NSString`.

Comment: @JasonWhitehorn check the link I replied to Donnie with.