# Is it redundant to check isKindOfClass in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

**Is it redundant to check isKindOfClass even for non id variables in Objective C?**

Teammate wrote Swift code. I am reviewing. Do I really need to check with `isKindOfClass` in the condition or its redundant?

```
-(void) checkCalorie:(NSMutableDictionary *) update {

    NSString *foodInfoId = [update objectForKey:FOOD_INFO_ID];
    double calorie = [[update objectForKey:CALORIE] doubleValue];
    if ([foodInfoId isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && calorie < 0)
    {
        calorie = 0.0;
        // some logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Code review entry is deleted. Please unvote. @Roman

Comment: "even for non id variables"? Why ? You know that `NSString *foodInfoId = [update objectForKey:FOOD_INFO_ID];`, there is nothing that confirms that `fooldInfoId` is really a `NSString` object, right? So, checking the class might be relevant. It really depends on your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should refactor this code with the `dynamic_cast` implemented for Objective-C. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557756/objective-c-dynamic-cast) for inspiration. For instance, use `objc_dynamic_cast` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10557838/2229783), and then you will have the following code:

```
-(void)checkCalorie:(NSMutableDictionary *)update {
    NSString *foodInfoId = objc_dynamic_cast([update objectForKey:FOOD_INFO_ID], NSString);
    double calorie = [[update objectForKey:CALORIE] doubleValue];
    if (foodInfoId != nil && calorie < 0) {
        calorie = 0.0;
        // some logic
    }
}
```